# React hooks state is undefined when updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple React Hooks component. When I try and update the lightState using the setLightState function it returns `undefined` for the current state. Accessing the state inside the return body works fine.

```js
const MainControl = () => {
  const [lightState, setLightState] = useState()
  const [lightChan, setLightChan] = useState()

  const updateLight = (newState) => {
    setLightState({...lightState, ...newState})
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    socket.connect()
    let chan = socket.channel("lights:dioder")

    chan.join().receive("ok", (response) => {
      setLightState(response)
      setLightChan(chan)
    })

    chan.on("light_colour", (resp) => {
      updateLight(resp)
    })

    return () => {
      chan.leave()
    }
  }, [])

  if (!lightChan) return <h2>Loading...</h2>

  return (
     <h2>Lights are currently {lightState.on ? "on" : "off"}</h2>
  )
}
```

The `updateLight` function reads `lightState` as `undefined`, but the return body does not? I think this may only be true on the first render but I'm not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateLight(resp)` is use in the callback function of `chan.on`, when you declare `chan.on` the `lightState` is undefined. So whenever callback of `chan.on` is trigger the value of `setLightState` is undefined (Closure of JS).
If you want to set new state using previous state value, you need to pass a function to `setLightState`

```
setLightState(prevLightState => ({...prevLightState, ...newState}))
```

Comment: This feels so convoluted. I don't understand why a function is required to simply update a value.

Answer (score 0):

When you're initializing your state with `useState` you aren't setting an initial value for `lightState`.  You can initialize it as an empty object `useState({})` and it should work.

Also see using `useCallback` to update function params when dependent variables change.

See [declaring a state variable](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable) and [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix the issue as when I set the state on subsequent renders, It ignores the initial state/loads it as `undefined`